# How to capture string of characters from where it is indicated to the first point followed by a line break?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```py
import re

x = """44
5844 44554  Hi hi!   , sahhashash; asakjas. jjksakjaskjas.
ooooooppkkk"""

#both initial after the last line break that they have within their capture range
# ((?:\w+)?)   ---> with a capturing group this pattern can capture a substring of alphanumeric characters (uppercase and lowercase) until it is taken with a space, a comma or a dot
# ((?:\w\s*)+)   ---> this pattern is similar to the previous one but it does not stop when finding spaces
regex_patron_m1 = r"\s*((?:\w+)?) \s*\¿?(?:del |de |)\s*((?:\w\s*)+)\s*\??"

m1 = re.search(regex_patron_m1, x, re.IGNORECASE) #Con esto valido la regex haber si entra o no en el bloque de code

if m1:
    word, association = m1.groups()
    
    print(repr(word)) #print captured substring by first capture group
    print(repr(association)) #print captured substring by second capture group
```

The output that I get with this two patterns

```
'5844'
'44554  Hi hi'
```

What should I modify to get the following? since I don't understand why both capture groups start their capture after the newline

And what should I do so that the capture of the second capture group is up to the full stop point `".[\s|]*\n*"` or `".\n*"`?  To get

```
'44'
'5844 44554  Hi hi!   , sahhashash; asakjas. jjksakjaskjas.'
```

And if I didn't want it to stop at the line break, to get something like this, what should I do?

```
'44'
'5844 44554  Hi hi!   , sahhashash; asakjas. jjksakjaskjas.
ooooooppkkk'
```

Comment: Please stop using `print(repr(word))`. Use `print(word)` or you might see something you do not expect.

Comment: I only use that in the test to check the data format and because trailing and leading spaces and line breaks are important. It is also a way to check if it justifies or not using the `.strip()` . It is not the idea that it is in the final code, but it is more to visualize possible errors

Answer (score 0):

try this expression:

```
((\w+(\r|\n).*.)\n\w*)
```

group 1:

```
44
5844 44554  Hi hi!   , sahhashash; asakjas. jjksakjaskjas.
ooooooppkkk
```

group 2:

```
44
5844 44554  Hi hi!   , sahhashash; asakjas. jjksakjaskjas.
```

hope this is what you were looking for.

EDIT:
I don't know if I well undertood your question, but try this one:

```
(\w+)\n(.*\n\w+)
```

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/3HqYjf/1)

Comment: That expression corresponds to the first or second capture group? For some reason it is not working for me

Comment: the expression captures both groups. see the demo 
 here : https://regex101.com/r/cUbVKQ/1

Comment: I didn't try it with your code

Comment: The problem is that there are 2 capture groups, one that does not accept empty spaces, and the other that does, but both must be limited by line breaks.

Comment: I see your last edit, I need 2 capture groups that captures, `((?:\w+)?)` --> "44"  ,  `((?:\w\s*)+)`  --> `"5844 44554  Hi hi!   , sahhashash; asakjas. jjksakjaskjas."` , but I can't capture those 2 substrings using my capture groups, so I needed help to find some capture groups that do work. I have tried to do this with the capture groups that you gave me `r"\s*((\w+(\r|\n).*.)\n\w*) \s*\¿?(?:del |de |)\s*(\w+)\n(.*\n\w+)\s*\??"` ,but it did not work directly for me

Comment: so you want the first group to capture alpha numeric chracters and stop at first occurence of comma dot or space, and the second group to capture from the begining any alphanumeric character with comma, dot and space BUT stop at the end of line??is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Create a string containing line breaks

```
Newline code \n（LF）, \r\n（CR + LF）

Triple quote ''' or """

With indent
```

Concatenate a list of strings on new lines

Split a string into a list by line breaks: splitlines()

Remove or replace line breaks

Output with print() without a trailing newline

Comment: The problem is that there are 2 capture groups, one that does not accept empty spaces, and the other that does, but both must be limited by line breaks. The capture groups that I put have the problem that they do not start in the correct place (as seen in the example), but rather do so after a line break, also they do not stop their capture in the proper place